# why the thread runs only once?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

This is my client:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.simpledialog
import socket
import select
import ssl
import threading
Host = '127.0.0.1'
Port = 87
def create_connection():
    return socket.create_connection((Host, Port))

def gui():
    global e1
    global txt
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Amifre chat')
    root.geometry("700x515")
    txt = Text(root, width=70, height=30)
    txt.config(state=DISABLED)
    e1 = Entry(root, width=93)
    e1.place(x=0, y=487)
    txt.place(x=0)
    t = threading.Thread(target=display_msg())
    t.daemon = True
    root.after(1, t.start())
    root.mainloop()

def display_msg():
    r, w, x = select.select([client_socket], [], [], 0.00001)
    if client_socket in r:
        data = client_socket.recv().decode()
        txt.config(state=NORMAL)
        txt.insert(INSERT, data + '\n')
        txt.config(state=DISABLED)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = Tk()
    b = Button(start, text='Click to join the chat', command=create_user_name).grid(row=0)
    context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
    client_socket = create_connection()
    client_socket = context.wrap_socket(client_socket, server_hostname='127.0.0.1')
    start.mainloop()
    gui()
```

This is a client for chat and the thread in the gui function call the display_msg function only once so does anyone have any idea why is it? (sending data works well and it dislplayed in client without GUI)

Comment: Should be `target=display_msg` without `()` and no need to use `root.after()` to start the thread, just call `t.start()`.

Comment: I changed it and it still doesn't work

Comment: You should use while loop inside `display_msg()`.  Also note that updating tkinter widget in child thread may cause problem as tkinter is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass only the function name to `target` option, and call `t.start()` directly without using `after()`:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=display_msg, daemon=True)
t.start()
```

Then, you need to use while loop inside `display_msg()` to keep receiving data from server:

```
def display_msg():
    while True:
        r, w, x = select.select([client_socket], [], [])
        if client_socket in r:
            data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
            txt.config(state=NORMAL)
            txt.insert(INSERT, data + '\n')
            txt.config(state=DISABLED)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=display_msg())
```

is functionally identical to this code:

```
result = display_msg()
t = threading.Thread(result)
```

And this code:

```
root.after(1, t.start())
```

is functionally identical to this code:

```
result = t.start()
root.after(1, result)
```

In both `threading.Thread` and `after`, the values given to the functions must be *references* to a function rather than the *result* of a function (unless the result is itself a reference to a function).

```
t = threading.Thread(target=display_msg)
...
root.after(1, t.start)
```

Regardless, the answer to *"why the thread runs only once?"* is because that's what threads do. Threads run until they are done. If you need code to run in a loop, you will need to write the loop yourself.

Comment: @amifre: `mainloop` loops over a queue of events. It doesn't loop over your code.

Comment: ok thanks. do you have any idea how can i loop the thread? because when I tried the while loop I still couldn't run the function several times

Comment: @amifre: like the answer says, if you want it to loop you have to add your own loop. A `while` loop is one way to do it.